# iOS: Crash at setSelectedViewController in tabBarController

Tags: ios

I am working on an iOS app, where-in i have a tabbar controller and respective view controllers. For each tab in tabbar controller set with an view controller. This setup is done in .xib file itself.
But still, in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions i am adding the below code as well to launch default view as second tab view when my app launches,

```
self.viewController = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.tabBarController setSelectedViewController:self.viewController]; // crash
```

What happens here is, its working fine on iOS 4 simulator and device, but the crash is happening in the second line of this code in iOS 5 simulator and device. We are trying to find out why it crashes only on iOS 5 devices/simulators, still couldn't be able conclude it. If the view controllers are already setup in .xib file itself, then i don't need to instantiate the object and do setup like this in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions from iOS5?
What could the reason for this crash, please advise.

Thank you!

Comment: What specific error do you get with the crash? Something to the effect of, instance <something> does not respond to selector setSelectedViewController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `setSelectedViewController`, the controller has to be one in the tab bar controller's `viewControllers` array. But you're creating a new controller here, so it would necessarily fail. You should just use `setSelectedIndex`. That's easiest.

So, if you're using NIBs, the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` might look like:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // tell the tab bar controller to start with the second tab

    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];

    return YES;
}
```

If using storyboards, and your initial controller is that tab bar controller, you can:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    [tabController setSelectedIndex:1];

    return YES;
}
```