# Objective C - Error changing button on tab bar to another programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, tabbar

I try to change from one tab button to another tab button using:

`[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];`

But it makes crash my app:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception `NSRangeException`, reason: `Cannot remove an observer <SearchResultsViewController 0x100a4c3a0>` for the key path "results" from  because it is not registered as an observer.

Thanks,

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016588/ios-crash-at-setselectedviewcontroller-in-tabbarcontroller

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is that I am using storyboards, and my initial controller is not that tab bar controller. I don´t know how to adapt this solution...